# How do I append array items to a string over a loop in puppet

Tags: puppet

lets say I have an array with directory names

```
dirs = ['opt', 'apps', 'apache']
```

I want to iterate and generate a list of following paths

```
/opt
/opt/apps
/opt/apps/apache
```

through which I can create file resource.

Comment: Puppet won't allow to reassign a variable due to which I couldn't get desired output.

Comment: Coincidentally, I happened to answer this almost a month ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41041549/puppet-adding-array-elements-in-a-loop

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you want to iterate through those files like that?

Because the simplest way to turn those into file resources would be this:

```
$dirs = ['/opt', '/opt/apps', '/opt/apps/apache']

file { $dirs:
  ensure => directory,
}
```

If you just want to make sure that all the preceeding directories are created,  there is also the `dirtree` module, which will do this all for you:

https://forge.puppet.com/pltraining/dirtree

```
$apache_dir = dirtree('/opt/apps/apache')
# Will return: ['/opt', '/opt/apps', '/opt/apps/apache']
```

You can then use that variable to create the directories.

As Matt mentions, you can also use maps, or an iterator to create the resources.

Basic example here:

```
$dirs = ['/opt', '/opt/apps', '/opt/apps/apache']

$dirs.each |String $path| {
  file {$path:
    ensure => directory,
  }
}
```

Documented here: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_iteration.html

There are a few different ways to do what you want to do in the code, it depends on how much management you want to do of those resources after creation.

Comment: I decided to go with array of absolute paths. thanks @Peter